# SpringBoot Cloud Foundry override Database Pool Size - Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

After researching I have found that a default pool size of 4 is created by Spring Boot when deploying to the cloud.  I am deploying to Cloud Foundry, using Spring Boot 1.3.7, and connecting to a MySQL service.  I would like to increase the default pool size.  I am following the steps outlined in the this blog, but I am getting the error below. I do not have an issue connecting to the DB when using autoconfiguration with the service, so the DB is accessible.  Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!!!

https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry

```html
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.14-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2018-08-14 18:13:48.142  INFO 14 --- [           main] o.s.c.s.r.PooledDataSourceCreator        : Found Tomcat JDBC connection pool on the classpath. Using it for DataSource connection pooling.
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.42-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2018-08-14 18:13:48.422  WARN 14 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : initialSize is larger than maxActive, setting initialSize to: 4
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.42-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2018-08-14 18:13:48.422  WARN 14 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 4
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2018-08-14 18:13:48.587 ERROR 14 --- [           main] o.a.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool      : Unable to create initial connections of pool.
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:988) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:632) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1018) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar!/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar!/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:710) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar!/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:644) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar!/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:466) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar!/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:143) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar!/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar!/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar!/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:126) [tomcat-jdbc-8.0.36.jar!/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) [spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) [spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:338) [spring-jdbc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getDefaultDdlAuto(JpaProperties.java:198) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getOrDeduceDdlAuto(JpaProperties.java:186) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.getAdditionalProperties(JpaProperties.java:165) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties$Hibernate.access$000(JpaProperties.java:126) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.getHibernateProperties(JpaProperties.java:123) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.java:99) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:115) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78272a93.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$9(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78272a93$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3ece12ed.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$78272a93.entityManagerFactory(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) [spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.7.RELEASE]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.emc.it.pcf.rest.api.Application.main(Application.java:25) [app/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54) [app/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:104) [app/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:61) [app/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [app/:na]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.fill(ReadAheadInputStream.java:101) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
   2018-08-14T14:13:48.58-0400 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT     at com.mysql.jdbc.util.ReadAheadInputStream.readFromUnderlyingStreamIfNecessary(ReadAheadInputStream.java:144) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.39.jar!/:5.1.39]
```

```css
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class DatasourceCloudConfig extends AbstractCloudConfig {

  //switch off build pack and spring boot autoconfiguration
  @Bean
  public Cloud cloud() {
       return new CloudFactory().getCloud();
  }
  
  //Does not work
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(DataSourceProperties.PREFIX)
  public DataSource dataSource() {
 DataSource ds= connectionFactory().dataSource("pcf-rest-api-mysql");    
    return ds;
  }
  
  /*//Did not work
   * @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(DataSourceProperties.PREFIX)
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return cloud().getSingletonServiceConnector(DataSource.class, null);
  }*/
  
  /*//Did not work
   * @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = DataSourceProperties.PREFIX)
 public DataSource dataSource() {
  return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
 }*/  

}
```

```css
spring.datasource.driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    spring.datasource.initial-size: 20
    spring.datasource.testWhileIdle: true
    spring.datasource.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis:  3600000
    spring.datasource.validationQuery:  SELECT 1
    spring.datasource.remove-abandoned-timeout: 120
```

```css
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <parent>
  <groupId>xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
  <artifactId>cpe-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
 
 <groupId>xxx.xxx.xxx</groupId>
 <artifactId>pcf-rest-api</artifactId>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <name>pcf-rest-api</name>
 <version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <start-class>cxxx.xxx.xxx.Application</start-class>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>  
  
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        </dependency>        

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-spring-service-connector</artifactId>
  </dependency> 

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector</artifactId>
  </dependency> 
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>cglib</groupId>
   <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.cloudfoundry</groupId>
   <artifactId>cloudfoundry-client-lib</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency> 

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
   <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- EH Cache dependencies -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
   <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
   </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  </dependency>

 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
   <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
  </dependency>

     <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  </dependency> 
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  </dependency> 
    
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency> 

  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
   <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- Email -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
   <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <!-- Mapping -->
  <dependency>
      <groupId>ma.glasnost.orika</groupId>
     <artifactId>orika-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version><!-- or latest version -->
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
   <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
   <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
 
  <dependency>
      <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
      <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
 
 </dependencies>
 
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am all set.  For some reason spring boot was picking up the database connection URL from my local application.yml file instead of using the Cloud Foundry Service in the manifest.yml of my deployment.  When I removed the connection information from the local application.yml it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say exactly what happened, but a couple things you can do here.

1. If you want to use Spring Cloud Connectors, like in your example above, you need to set a PoolConfig. See the last two examples [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html#_relational_database_db2_mysql_oracle_postgresql_sql_server) or the following snippet.

   ```
   @Bean
   public DataSource dataSource() {
       PoolConfig poolConfig = new PoolConfig(5, 30, 3000);
       DataSourceConfig dbConfig = new DataSourceConfig(poolConfig, null);
       return connectionFactory().dataSource("my-own-personal-sql", dbConfig);
   }
   ```
2. You can use [Spring profiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html). By default, the Java buildpack is going to enable the "cloud" profile for your application, so you can put anything you only want active when running on Cloud Foundry in that profile. You can then create a "local" profile, or something like that, where you can put your apps configuration for when it's running locally on your PC (you do need to enable this profile, it won't happen automatically).

   In this way the contents of the two profiles won't overlap, but at the same time you don't have to manually swap settings based on the environment where your app is running.

For what it's worth, Spring Boot's `--debug` option and/or raising log levels for `org.springframework.cloud` to DEBUG would help to debug issues like this. You should see more details.